# Remove unused CTEs from a SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, common-table-expression

I have a query with many CTEs and more than 1000 lines, which returns about 60 columns. On some dbs it takes too long to execute (may even exit with timeout error), so I want to split the query into 2 parts, so that each part will get around half of columns, and then I will merge the 2 results based on some unique id using a python script or Excel. To get the 2 parts I basically remove some columns from the final select statement and want also to delete all CTEs which are not going to be used in a query. To automate this problem, I am wondering if there is a tool to remove the CTEs which will not be required for the "split" query, but may be computed and thus can waste memory and time resources.

Comment: I don't think CTEs are evaluated if they are not used in the main query.

Comment: (1) Check your query plan to see if a particular CTE is being executed (2) Even if you have a lot of CTEs, it's probably easier just to search for their names in the subsequent code and delete them if they are  not being used - rather than trying to automate a solution

Comment: @NickW, I run explain (analyze on , timing on) before the query and see, e.g. such lines:
"  CTE carbon_nanotube"
"    ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=6.30..4848.69 rows=1 width=62) (never executed)"
Does that mean the carbon_nanotube CTE will not affect time performance?

Comment: You need to run the query and look at the execution plan to see what has actually happened - EXPLAIN is a bit more theoretical but I would assume that "never executed" means what it says